# Best approach to use require in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dependency-injection, node-modules

I need to know the difference between these two approaches developer uses in nodeJS development to include a module.

> 1. First approach (passing module in app by importing it once and using it by passing as parameter or binding it to app as property )

**Server.js** (app entry point)

```
let app = require('express').express();
let Router = require("./routes");
let SomeModule = require("./some-module");
.....
.....

Router.mountAPI("/api", app, SomeModule);
.....
....
```

**routes.js** (Passing pre imported module to controllers in different files )

```
let Ctrl1fun = require("./ctrl1");
let Ctrl2fun = require("./ctrl2");

exports.mountAPI = function(mount, app, SomeModuleToUseInController) {
    app.use(mount + '/endpoint1', Ctrl1fun(SomeModuleToUseInController));
    app.use(mount + '/endpoint2', Ctrl2fun(SomeModuleToUseInController));
};
```

**ctrl1.js** (Controller for end point 1 )

```
module.exports = function(SomeModule) {
....
....
//using SomeModule
}
// This file may contain some other controller function for simplicity i took only one
```

**ctrl2.js** (Controller for end point 2 )

```
module.exports = function(SomeModule) {
....
....
//using SomeModule
}
// This file may contain some other controller function for simplicity i took only one
```

> 2.Second approach (Each controller importing the module)

**Server.js** (app entry point)

```
let app = require('express').express();
let Router = require("./routes");
.....
.....

Router.mountAPI("/api", app);
.....
....
```

**routes.js** (module imported in controllers )

```
let Ctrl1fun = require("./ctrl1");
let Ctrl2fun = require("./ctrl2");

exports.mountAPI = function(mount, app) {
    app.use(mount + '/endpoint1', Ctrl1fun());
    app.use(mount + '/endpoint2', Ctrl2fun());
};
```

**ctrl1.js** (Controller for end point 1 )

```
let SomeModule = require("./some-module");

module.exports = function() {
....
....
//using SomeModule
}
// This file may contain some other controller function for simplicity i took only one
```

**ctrl2.js** (Controller for end point 2 )

```
let SomeModule = require("./some-module");
module.exports = function() {
....
....
//using SomeModule
}
// This file may contain some other controller function for simplicity i took only one
```

***Witch one is better if we consider***

1. App size (API and controllers function in different controller files)
2. Application performance
3. Best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in terms of size and performance will be negligible.

The second approach is simpler and I would consider it as the best one unless you need to inject different modules into the same controller type, e.g. a generic CRUD controller parameterized by model type

Comment: Hi @Jonas, Do second approach take more memory space then first one ?

Comment: No, I don't see why it would

Comment: Because we are including the same module in different files, don't it going to extend the application run time memory requirements by including it multiple time, Or its going to load on module only once?

Comment: No, the node module cache will ensure that each module is loaded only once.

Comment: Got it thanks @Jonas http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/